# SQL server table partitioning on current date

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, azure-sql-database, database-partitioning

I have big table . This table has eventDate column . I need to partition this table on two parts . The first part will contain the records where (currentDate - 10 days > eventDate) and the second part - the others . In other words ,the first part should contain the last 10 days records.

Can I achieve it?

Comment: Obviously, yes. Check the tutorials or the partitioning wizard in SSMS itself. It would be a bad idea though, you'd have to move data from one partition to the other every day

Comment: How big is the big table and why do you want only two partitions with one just 10 days?

Comment: You'd have to run a daily job to change the partitioning - the scheme requires constant values.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with partitioning? Why not create montly partitions instead? How much data do you have? Partitioning is meant for tables of millions of rows. With such sizes, using only two partitions isn't very helpful

Comment: **Can you achieve it?** Absolutely. Search for example on implementing a rolling window partitioning scheme. **Is it a good idea?** It depends on your actual requirements. Having to move data from the "10-day" partition to the "old" partition every day is not that hard. **Is it easily implemented?** No, it is not.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos,I make join to this table,I want to optimize query .I want to make join not to all table,but to first part of partiton

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,you said "you'd have to move data from one partition to the other every day ",you mean I need write some script to do it . Is there way when sql server do it

Comment: @cosset that' doesn't explain anything. The optimizer will search only the latest entries *if* you have the appropriate indexes. Partitioning won't help at all if you don't have any indexes on the date column. *How many rows do you have ?*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,about 1000000 ,and it growth

Comment: @cosset please specify how big the table is and its distribution - how many rows are in that 10 day period and how many outside it? It sounds like you *assumed* you need partitioning when you may need more indexes or to rewrite the query.

Comment: @cosset that's not much. You don't need partitioning, unless you encountered significant delays. Did you? What is your query? What is the execution plan? Is there an index on `eventDate`? Did you try `Analyze Query` on your query ?